# `testl` eax against eax?

Tags: assembly, x86, instructions

I am trying to understand some assembly.

The assembly as follows, I am interested in the `testl` line:

```
000319df  8b4508        movl   0x08(%ebp), %eax  
000319e2  8b4004        movl   0x04(%eax), %eax  
000319e5  85c0          testl  %eax, %eax  
000319e7  7407          je     0x000319f0
```

I am trying to understand that point of `testl` between `%eax` and `%eax`? I think the specifics of what this code isn't important, I am just trying to understand the test with itself - wouldn't the value always be true?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It tests whether `eax` is 0, or above, or below. In this case, the jump is taken if `eax` is 0.

Comment: I made an edit to turn this popular answer into a better canonical answer to "what's this TEST thing all about, and how is it different from CMP", which is sort of implied.  See my own answer further down for comments about the semantic meaning of the synonymous JE and JZ.  Please review my edit since it's pretty major, and it's still your answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes I appreciate the intention, but I'm going to revert your edit. 1. Your "voice" is very different from mine, and right now it reads a lot more like your answer than mine. 2. More problematic is the bold assertion that the flags come out exactly the same way between `test` and `cmp`. Yes, I understand that's your belief based on your comments to Cody. However, putting it in my post is a different matter; it's not an assertion I'm willing to stand by, simply because _I don't know_ if it's identical in all cases.

Comment: @PeterCordes I understand the wish to have a "canonical" answer, but I think your answer has to swim or sink on its own merits, rather than piggyback on an accepted answer. I've had to do that for some of my answers to very popular questions too, like [the floating-point primer one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27030789/13), which at the time of posting my answer already had other answers with 500+ upvotes.

Comment: @PeterCordes If I find some spare time, I do want to flesh this answer out to be more canonical. I would write it like I write it, though, and I'm quite particular about how I write things. :-) For example, I'd write `je`, `jz`, `cmp`, and `test`, and not JE, JZ, CMP, or TEST. I'm picky like that.

Comment: I wasn't trying to boost my own answer.  I actually forgot that I'd answered this question myself when I made that edit, and only noticed afterwards.  I just looked at this after someone bumped it, and what started as a small edit snowballed into too much.  No offence taken that you wanted to roll it back; it was just a suggestion and it definitely reads like my work, not yours.  I'll take some of what I wrote and put it into my own answer.

Comment: Wow, after editing my answer to this question to include what I added to yours, I realized I had almost exactly duplicated most of what I wrote in June.  Oops!  I updated it with more reasoning to back up my claim that `test a,a` and `cmp $0,a` set flags identically; thanks for pointing out that that's a non-trivial claim.  re: TEST vs. `test`: recently I've started using all-caps like Intel's manuals.  But when I'm talking about AT&T mnemonics vs. Intel mnemonics, I use `testb` style for AT&T.  IDK if that helps readability.

Answer (score 102):

The meaning of `test` is to AND the arguments together, and check the result for zero. So this code tests if EAX is zero or not. `je` will jump if zero.

BTW, this generates a smaller instruction than `cmp eax, 0` which is the reason that compilers will generally do it this way.

Answer (score 35):

The test instruction does a logical AND-operation between the operands but does not write the result back into a register. Only the flags are updated.

In your example the test eax, eax will set the zero flag if eax is zero, the sign-flag if the highest bit set and some other flags as well.

The Jump if Equal (je) instruction jumps if the zero flag is set.

You can translate the code to a more readable code like this:

```
cmp eax, 0
je  somewhere
```

That has the same functionality but requires some bytes more code-space. That's the reason why the compiler emitted a test instead of a compare.

Comment: Actually, cmp might not work there.  That is, it works for the specific case presented, but cmp affects flags differently than test does, due to it being an internal sub instead of and.  Something to keep in mind.

Comment: for a test against zero it's perfectly valid.

Comment: But you don't know what else looks at the flags later.  The effects on flags are very different, so this can be an issue and very frequently is.

Comment: @Cody: As far as I can tell, the only flags that differ between the two are carry and overflow; doesn't seem like much of an obstacle to using 'test eax,eax' IMHO

Comment: No, the only flags that are set by a different /method/ are carry and overflow, both of which are set to 0.  The /values/ of the other flags will differ because cmp uses sub and test uses and.

Comment: @CodyBrocious: [`test eax, eax`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/TEST.html) and [`cmp eax, 0`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMP.html) both set all flags, and set them to identical values.  Both instructions set all flags "according to the result".  Subtracting `0` can never produce carry or overflow.  Your argument is correct for any immediate other than 0, but not for 0.

Answer (score 31):

[`test`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/TEST) is like [`and`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/AND), except it only writes FLAGS, leaving both its inputs unmodified.  With two *different* inputs, it's useful for testing if some bits are all zero, or if at least one is set.  (e.g. `test al, 3` sets ZF if EAX is a multiple of 4 (and thus has both of its low 2 bits zeroed).

---

**[`test eax,eax`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/TEST.html) sets all flags exactly the same way that [`cmp eax, 0`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMP.html) would**:

- CF and OF cleared  (AND/TEST always does that; subtracting zero never produces a carry)
- ZF, SF and PF according to the value in EAX.  (`a = a&a = a-0`).
  (PF as usual [is only set according to the low 8 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404539/intel-assembly-test-pf-flag-operation/47405136#47405136))

Except for the obsolete AF (auxiliary-carry flag, used by ASCII/BCD instructions).  [TEST leaves it undefined](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html), but [CMP sets it "according to the result"](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/TEST.html).  Since subtracting zero can't produce a carry from the 4th to 5th bit, CMP should always clear AF.

---

TEST is smaller (no immediate) and sometimes faster (can macro-fuse into a compare-and-branch uop on more CPUs in more cases than CMP).  [**That makes `test` the preferred idiom for comparing a register against zero**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/x86-assembly-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806).  It's a peephole optimization for `cmp reg,0` that you can use regardless of the semantic meaning.

The only common reason for using CMP with an immediate 0 is when you want to compare against a memory operand. For example, `cmpb $0, (%esi)` to check for a terminating zero byte at the end of an implicit-length C-style string.

---

**AVX512F adds [`kortestw k1, k2`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/KORTESTW_KORTESTB_KORTESTQ_KORTESTD)** and AVX512DQ/BW (Skylake-X but not KNL) add [`ktestb/w/d/q k1, k2`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/KTESTW_KTESTB_KTESTQ_KTESTD), which operate on AVX512 mask registers (k0..k7) but still set regular FLAGS like `test` does, the same way that integer `OR` or `AND` instructions do.  (Sort of like SSE4 `ptest` or SSE `ucomiss`: inputs in the SIMD domain and result in integer FLAGS.)

`kortestw k1,k1` is the idiomatic way to branch / cmovcc / setcc based on an AVX512 compare result, replacing SSE/AVX2 `(v)pmovmskb/ps/pd` + `test` or `cmp`.

---

**Use of `jz` vs. `je` can be confusing.**

[`jz` and `je` are literally the same instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html), i.e. the same opcode in the machine code.  **They do the same thing, but have different semantic meaning for humans**.  Disassemblers (and typically asm output from compilers) will only ever use one, so the semantic distinction is lost.

`cmp` and `sub` set ZF when their two inputs are equal (i.e. the subtraction result is 0).  `je` (jump if equal) is the semantically relevant synonym.

`test %eax,%eax` / `and %eax,%eax` again sets ZF when the result is zero, but there's no "equality" test.  ZF after test doesn't tell you whether the two operands were equal.  So `jz` (jump if zero) is the semantically relevant synonym.

Comment: I would consider adding the basic information about `test` being bitwise `and` operation, may be not obvious for people just learning assembly (and being lazy/unaware to check instruction reference guide every 60 seconds ;) :) ).

Comment: @Ped7g: fair enough, I guess it doesn't hurt to put everything in this answer, instead of leaving that part to the other answers.  Added AVX512 `kortest*` and `ktest*` while I was at it.

Comment: BTW, this basically the same as [my answer to another version of the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806), but I said more stuff about performance there, e.g. possibly avoiding register-read stalls on old P6-family CPUs like Nehalem by rewriting the register with the same value.

Comment: @PeterCordes This should be the accepted answer : exhaustive and technical. Unlike the accepted post, this quenches one's curiosity and thirst for knowledge. Keep it up Sir.

Comment: It should be noted that PF is set to the parity of the low 8 bits, which in this case is AL.

Comment: @ecm: yeah, I think I can throw that in with distracting and cluttering too much.  That's what "setting PF according to the result" always means, but that can still be surprising.

Answer (score 5):

This snippet of code is from a subroutine that was given a pointer to something, probably some struct or object. The 2nd line dereferences that pointer, fetching a value from that thing - possibly itself a pointer or maybe just an  int, stored as its 2nd member (offset +4).  The 3rd and 4th lines test this value for zero (NULL if it's a pointer) and skip the following few operations (not shown) if it is zero.

The test for zero sometimes is coded as a compare to an immediate literal zero value, but the compiler (or human?) who wrote this might have thought a testl op would run faster - taking into consideration all the modern CPU stuff like pipelining and register renaming.  It's from the same bag of tricks that holds the idea of clearing a register with XOR EAX,EAX (which i saw on someone's license plate in Colorado!) rather than the obvious but maybe slower MOV EAX, #0 (i use an older notation).

In asm, like perl, TMTOWTDI.

Answer (score 3):

If eax is zero it will perform the conditional jump, otherwise it will continue execution at 319e9

Answer (score 0):

In some programs they can be used to check for a buffer overflow. 
At the very top of the allocated space a 0 is placed. After inputting data into the stack, it looks for the 0 at the very beginning of the allocated space to make sure the allocated space is not overflowed.

It was used in the stack0 exercise of exploits-exercises to check if it was overflowed and if there wasnt and there was a zero there, it would display "Try again"

```
0x080483f4 <main+0>:    push   ebp
0x080483f5 <main+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x080483f7 <main+3>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x080483fa <main+6>:    sub    esp,0x60                     
0x080483fd <main+9>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c],0x0 ;puts a zero on stack
0x08048405 <main+17>:   lea    eax,[esp+0x1c]
0x08048409 <main+21>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x0804840c <main+24>:   call   0x804830c <gets@plt>
0x08048411 <main+29>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c] 
0x08048415 <main+33>:   test   eax,eax                  ; checks if its zero
0x08048417 <main+35>:   je     0x8048427 <main+51>
0x08048419 <main+37>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048500 
0x08048420 <main+44>:   call   0x804832c <puts@plt>
0x08048425 <main+49>:   jmp    0x8048433 <main+63>
0x08048427 <main+51>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048529
0x0804842e <main+58>:   call   0x804832c <puts@plt>
0x08048433 <main+63>:   leave
0x08048434 <main+64>:   ret
```

Comment: I don't see what this specific case of checking a register for non-zero adds to this Q&A.  Especially when `cmp DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c], 0` / `jz 0x8048427 <main+51>` would have been more efficient than a separate MOV-load and then TEST.  This is hardly a common use-case for checking for a zero.

Answer (score -4):

we could see the **jg**，**jle**
If `testl  %edx,%edx. jle   .L3`we could easy find **jle**is suit `(SF^OF)|ZF`,if %edx is zero ,ZF=1,but if %edx is not zero and is -1,after the testl ,the OF=0,and the SF =1,so the flag =true,that implement jump
.sorry ,my English is poor