# How to check if a signed integer is neg or pos?

Tags: assembly, x86, negative-number, negative-integer

I am new to x86 assembly language, I have a signed integer saved in register `eax`, and I want to check if the number is negative or positive. To do that, I used `bt` instruction to check the first bit.

Here is what I did:

```
bt eax,0
jnc isNegative
```

`bt` loads the first bit to carry flag, and I used `jnc` to check if carry flag is 0 or 1.

If it's 1, it should be a negative number, and does negative instructions...
however, the output is unpredictable, sometimes I have a positive and it recognize it as a negative number. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I just realized it could have something to do with bit numbering. It is actually checking the least significant bit instead of the first bit. Let me try using `bt eax, 31`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The value is negative if the MSB is set.  The SF (sign flag) in FLAGS is set according to that bit of the result.

```
test eax, eax      ; set FLAGS according to the value in EAX; like cmp eax, 0
js   negative      ; jump if top bit was set in EAX
```

---

Alternatively since [`test reg,reg` sets FLAGS the same way as `cmp reg,0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg), you could use `jl` to jump if the value is "less than zero".  That's the same thing.  Fun fact: this also works as a trick for optimizing unsigned `if(eax >= 0x80000000U)`.

You can manually do it as a single-bit test (not taking advantage of SF) with a less efficient instruction (longer because it has to include the 32-bit constant.)  This is a lot like your `bt eax,31` but setting ZF=0 instead of CF=1 when the sign bit is set.

```
test eax, 0x80000000      ; set flags according to EAX & (1<<31)
jnz  negative             ; jump if that result was non-zero, i.e. bit was set
```

This works for any register size, byte (int8_t), word (int16_t), dword (int32_t), or qword (int64_t).  For example with bytes:

```
test al, al
js   is_negative
; or
test al, 80h
jne  is_negative
```

---

If the value in a register was produced by something that sets FLAGS "according to the result", like most ALU instructions such as [`add ecx, edx`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add#flags-affected), you can `js` to see if it's negative or not without needing to `test ecx, ecx` first.  SF is already set according to the MSB of the value in ECX, by the `add` instruction.

---

#### Terminology: positive doesn't include zero

- positive is `x > 0`.  Numbers 1 or greater, not including zero.  (Sometimes used loosely as the opposite of negative, but strictly speaking it's not.)
- non-negative is `x >= 0`.
- negative is `x < 0`.
- zero is not positive or negative.  Its 2's complement bit-pattern is all-zero, no bits set.  (x86 uses [2's complement signed integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), like all other modern CPUs.  That's why there's no integer negative-zero.)

So if you want to find out if a number is positive or negative, that's two separate checks unless you already know it's non-zero.  (Assuming you're using a strict definition of positive.  Sometimes from context you can infer that someone means one condition, but precise terminology is useful in computing so prefer that yourself.)

---

**Your `bt` idea could work**, but x86 numbers bits from bit 0 at the *bottom* (least significant), to bit 31 as the sign-bit of a 32-bit register like EAX.  Also, CF set means negative, so `jc negative`.  But `bt` isn't faster unless you actually want the condition in the carry flag for use with `adc edx, 0` to do `negcount += (x<0)` counting negative numbers or something.  Alternatively, `add eax,eax` or `shl eax,1` will shift the top bit of EAX into CF (and also modify EAX, unlike BT).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `jge` and `cmp` instructions:

```
cmp eax, 0
jl isNegative
```

Comment: Great, fixes the problem and simple! although, it should be cmp eax,0

Comment: Depends on which assembler you're using, but for Intel's, yes. I guess that's where the downvote came from.

Comment: cmp is longer than test so test is often preferred http://stackoverflow.com/a/147183/995714

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution checks if the number is even or odd, instead test the 31st bit:

```
bt eax, 31
jc number_is_negative
```

Or you can compare the number to zero, and test whether it's greater than or equal to it.

```
main:
    ...
    cmp eax, 0 ; Compare the number to zero
    jge .number_is_positive ; If it's positive jump to .number_is_positive
    ; And only arrive here if a number is negative
    ...
.number_is_positive:
    ; Yay! number is positive
    ...
```

Comment: Zero isn't positive.  `jge` jumps for non-negative numbers.