# Statement with multiple fork() s

Tags: c, fork

The child process begins executing at the exact point where the last one left off - after the fork statement. What if the statement contains multiple fork()s like the conditional expression like the following. Where exactly program execution starts for the child process. Before worrying about how many processes gets created, I wanted to know if every child process created tries to evaluate `fork() && fork() || fork();` statement. If it is so. How does a child process that got created because of second fork() statement have information from the first fork() to evaluate `fork() && fork()`.

```
main(){
fork() && fork() || fork();
}
```

Comment: That line just left an emotional scar in me

Comment: Why do these ludicrous fork questions keep cropping up occasionally?

Comment: +1 @Oli.  I presume they're terrible homework problems.

Comment: I bet they're from the same teacher even

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The child that results from the second `fork()` knows about the results of the first `fork()` because it is an *exact copy* of the parent process.

You can work out what happens by drawing a little tree for yourself.  Start with the first fork:

```
         fork()
           /\
          /  \
parent --/    \-- child1
```

The parent gets back the PID of the `child1` process, and `child1` gets back 0.  So we have something like:

```
PID(child1) && fork() || fork()
```

in the parent, and:

```
0 && fork() || fork()
```

in the child. Short circuiting means that the middle `fork()` of the original expression doesn't get executed in the child, only in the parent.  So now what happens to the tree?

```
                  fork()
                    /\
                   /  \
         parent --/    \-- child1
         fork()
           /\
          /  \
parent --/    \-- child2
```

`parent` is the original process, and gets the PID of `child2`.  `child2`, just like `child1`, gets 0.  What do our expressions look like now?

```
parent:  PID(child1) && PID(child2) || fork() = 1 || fork()
child:   0 || fork()
child2:  PID(child1) && 0 || fork() = 0 || fork()
```

Now, again by short-circuiting, `parent` is done, and doesn't execute the last `fork()`.  Both `child` and `child2` have to, however.  That leaves us with the following tree:

```
                     fork()
                       /\
                      /  \
            parent --/    \-- child1
            fork()            fork()
              /\                /\
             /  \              /  \
            /    \   child1 --/    \-- child1-1
           /      \
          /        \
parent --/          \-- child2
                        fork()
                          /\
                         /  \
               child2 --/    \-- child2-1
```

And that's it.  `child1` and `child2` each get the PID of their respective children, and `child1-1` and `child2-1` each get back 0.  Substituting those values in, the final expressions are:

```
parent:   1
child1:   0 || PID(child1-1) = 1
child2:   0 || PID(child2-1) = 1
child1-1: 0 || 0 = 0
child2-1: 0 || 0 = 0
```

And that's it - they all exit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what could be confusing. When the `fork` function is called, it creates a second process that is a duplicate of the existing process. Both processes continue from precisely where they left off. The child knows how to continue evaluating the same way the parent does because it has precisely the information it needs in precisely the place it needs it because it is a clone.

Comment: As far as the child that got created because of the second fork() call is concerned `fork() &&` does not exit. Then how come the expression `fork() && fork() || fork()` has a meaning for that child.

Comment: The same way it has meaning to the parent. The process is duplicated inside the fork call. Then each process continues, but processing a different return value.

Answer (score 1):

```
fork() && fork()
```

Is equivalent to writing:

```
pid_t x = fork();
if ( x > 0 )
{
    fork();
}
```

That is, the parent process will fork twice, since both conditions are evaluated; neither child will `fork()` since both return 0 from the fork. However, `fork() || fork ()` is equivalent to:

```
pid_t x = fork();
if ( x == 0 )
{
    fork();
}
```

So, the parent process will `fork()` once and its child will `fork()` once.

If you speak asm, try spitting out the output from these two expressions:

```
movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    call    fork
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .L3         // jump if eax is zero
    call    fork
    testl   %eax, %eax
    nop
.L3:
    call    fork
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jne .L7         // jump if eax is non-zero.
    call    fork
    testl   %eax, %eax
```

Note that `call fork` is the point at which your process loses control and then regains it with `eax` set to the return value. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147173/x86-assembly-testl-eax-against-eax) will help understand `testl`.

You should be able to work out what would happen in your combined example using the [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) rules.