# Use of TEST instruction with same register

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, instructions

Here is some C, found in a textbook I'm learning:

```
...
do {
    ...
    n--;
} while (n > 0)
...
```

I assume `n` is at `%edx`.

The assembly code produced is:

```
testl %edx, %edx 
jle .L5
```

I understand that `jle` tests for less than or equal to `(SF ^ OF) | ZF`. However I am unsure how this instruction corresponds to `n > 0`. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [x86 Assembly - 'testl' eax against eax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147173/x86-assembly-testl-eax-against-eax)

Comment: I do not believe so, he is using a different jump instruction.

Comment: It's still a comparison with 0, you can use any jump instruction after it.

Comment: @interjay but the explanation given there is not complete in this case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some of this has been covered, but I'll fill in a little more detail.

The general purpose of the `test reg,mask` instruction tests a register value against a mask (register value is internally ANDed with mask) and then sets the status flags SF, ZF, and PF according to the result. [EDIT per comment from @ChrisDodd] It also unconditionally clears the `O` (overflow) and `C` (carry) status bits.[/EDIT]

```
SF = sign flag (1 if sign bit is set (a 2's complement negative value))
ZF = zero flag (1 if result is 0)
PF = parity flag (1 if result has an even number of 1 bits)
```

In this specific example (`test eax,eax`), the instruction is taking `eax AND eax`. When this is done, the bits will be:

```
SF = 1 if EAX has a negative value (since sign bit will not change when ANDed with itself)
ZF = 1 if EAX is zero (the only value that yields a zero when ANDed with itself is zero)
PF = 1 if EAX has an even number of 1 bits
```

In other words, it's a simple test for zero or negative. It's a very common pattern in compiler code generation.

Comment: A critical additional fact is that the `test` instruction unconditionally clears the O and C flags.  Without that it would not be useful for comparisons against zero.

Comment: @ChrisDodd good info (+1). Thanks. If you don't mind, I shall add that to my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

`TEST` "sets the SF, ZF, and PF status flags according to the result." (Intel manual, about `TEST`).

So SF will reflect whether `n` was negative, and `ZF` will reflect whether `n` was zero.

It sets OF to zero.

So `(SF ^ OF)|ZF` simplifies to `SF | ZF`, so in conclusion, the jump will be taken if `n <= 0`. That seems the wrong way around, so hopefully .L5 is the label *after* the loop, not the label in front of the loop.