# How to check if a register is zero in x86_64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to check if a value is zero in x86_64 assembly code. I know that this usually consist of a `cmp` variant followed by a `jmp` variant, but I'm not sure of the exact instructions to use.

Comment: What is the type of variable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you've just used an instruction that modifies ZF before, simply check that flag and jump using `JZ` or `JE`. For example

```
and rax, rbx ; ZF was modified
jz  is_zero  ; so to check if rax is zero, a single jump is enough
```

If ZF was not set, you need to do that explicitly. The obvious way is

```
cmp rax, 0
je  equal_zero
```

However since `cmp` is longer if you look at the output binary, [`test`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/147173/995714) or sometimes [`and`, `or`](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/4656/2563) is preferred

```
83F800  cmp eax, 0
09C0    or eax, eax
85C0    test eax, eax
```

The resulting code will be

```
test rax, rax
jz   is_zero
```

You can get the assembly output from a compiler and check or view it in an online tool like [gcc godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'//+Type+your+code+here,+or+load+an+example.%0Aint+is_zero(int+x,+int+*y,+int+*z)+%7B%0A+++if+(x+%3D%3D+0)%0A+++++*y+%3D+*z%3B%0A+++else%0A+++++*y+%3D+-*z%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:25.650950254211345,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g71,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:35.5645638630054,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc17,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+icc+17+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:38.78448588278327,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Read more: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow

Answer (score 16):

```
test %eax, %eax   ; set ZF to 1 if eax == 0
je 0x804f430      ; jump to 0x00804f4 if ZF == 1
```

`ZF` is a single bit zero flag which will be set to 1 if `eax` be equal to zero.  `je` will take the jump to `0x804f430` if the `ZF` be set to 1.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Another correct answer is to replace the `test` with `cmp $0, %eax`.

Comment: @NayukiMinase test is shorter than cmp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147173/x86-assembly-testl-eax-against-eax?rq=1

Comment: `jz` might be a more mnemonic choice. (Of course it's the same instruction.)

Comment: I agree be nice if the answer said `JZ`