# Assembly testq and cmovg instruction

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, intel

What does the following do?

```
testq   %rdx, %rdx
cmovg   %rcx, %rax
```

I understand that testq is a bitwise and between two registers, but how does it works with the flags?
What would this translate into in c?
e.g. if `%rdx` would hold value `0x01`, then we'd have `0x01` & `0x01` = `0x01`, which would set

```
ZF = 0, SF = 0, OF = 0.
```

And for what I could find cmovg is performed if

```
˜(SF ˆ OF) & ˜ZF
```

which would resolve to

```
˜(0 ˆ 0) & ˜0 = ˜(0) & ˜0 = 1 & 1 = 1.
```

Would this mean that cmovg would be performed and that the corresponding c code would behave for `d = %rdx`, `a = rax` and `c = rcx`:

```
 if(d > 0){
   a = c;
 }
```

Or can someone maybe explain this in other words?

Additionally, i've been trying to work this assembly turning it into a corresponding c code. Currently i get a result that ends up like an infinite while loop on the testq %rdx, %rdx with jne .L4. With the content above enclosed. Anyone know what the right solution is? My current solution is this:

```
p:
        movq    (%rdi), %rdx
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
        je      .L5
        movl    $0, %eax
.L4:
        leaq    (%rax,%rdx), %rcx
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
        cmovg   %rcx, %rax
        addq    $8, %rdi
        movq    (%rdi), %rdx
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
        jne     .L4
        ret
.L5:
        movl    $0, %eax
        ret
```

Solution (wrong):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int func(int *rdi){
  int rdx = *rdi;
  if(rdx == 0){
    int rax = 0;
    return rax;
  }
  int rax = 0;
    do {
    int rcx = rax + rdx;
    if(rdx > 0){
      rax = rcx;
    }
    rdi += 8;
    rdx = *rdi;
  } while(rdx != 0);

  return rax;

}

  int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int var = 20;
    int *ip;
    ip = &var;
    func(ip);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.

Comment: @Jester alright, thanks. I was really in doubt >.<

Comment: In general, it can be useful to remember that `test %rdx, %rdx` is equivalent to `cmp 0, %rdx` (in backwards AT&T syntax), so if you see a "g" condition code you can easily realize that it means "if *g*reater than *zero*" (where "greater" means `>` for signed values, as opposed to "above" which means `>` for unsigned values).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Ah! thats a really great rule to remember. That'll help. Thanks :)

Comment: @MatteoItalia i added some additional code that is the whole translation of an assembly program to c. Im pretty sure i messed something up.
Got any idea where i went wrong?

Comment: Brush up what the parenthesis mean in the AT&T syntax and the solution will become clear ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Apart for AF, every other flag is set the same AFAIK. OF and CF are clear since x-0 never overflows. SF is set to the MSB of x since x-0 = x, same for ZF, and PF is set to XORNOT8(x-0) = XORNOT8(x). Considering that x AND x = x, these are the same results of `test`. Unless I overlooked something, I'm a bit burned-out right now :)

Comment: @MargaretBloom so something like this? (EDITED Solution).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Yes, `test %rdx,%rdx` sets flags identically to `cmp $0, %rdx` (apart from AF).
  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147173/testl-eax-against-eax/38032818#38032818 for reasoning / proof.

Comment: @Peter: So what is this question currently asking?  It seems to have morphed into a debug-my-code question without a [mcve].  Single-step your code in gdb or whatever debugger you prefer, and watch registers change (including FLAGS).  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for gdb tips.  If you're stuck on something you don't understand in the debugger, then put that in the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes Just an exercise i was doing, i couldnt really make it work - so i asked for some help. On my solution based on the assembly.

Comment: Yeah, but now there are at least 2 separate questions in one post.  See [ask]; this is not how we like our questions here at SO.  If you have an answer for your own question, post it as an *answer*.  (Answering your own question is encouraged if you have a good answer.)

Comment: I expanded a bit the comment in an answer, which could be the answer to the "original" question. The rest should probably be put in a separated question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(moving from the comment, replying to the original question)

> ```
> if(d > 0){
>     a = c;
> }
> ```

Yes, it's correct. Below I'll try to show how to "decode" this pattern quickly, without having to calculate all the times the flag register values.

> **Notice**: Intel syntax ahead, as it's way clearer for the operands order in comparisons; AT&T is similar but *with the operands reversed* (and more strange characters spread around).

The "numeric comparison" condition codes are best understood in the context of a "classic" sequence

```
cmp a, b
jCC label
```

The `CC` (condition code) part here refers to the "operator" (as in, `>`,`<`, `==`) that you are putting in the compare between `a` and `b`; so:

- `jg` → "**j**ump if `a` is **g**reater than `b`";
- `jl` → "**j**ump if `a` is **l**ess than `b`";
- `je` → "**j**ump if `a` is **e**qual to `b`";
- `jne` → "**j**ump if `a` is **n**ot **e**qual to `b`";
- `ja` → "**j**ump if `a` is **a**bove `b`";
- `jb` → "**j**ump if `a` is **b**elow `b`";
- ... all the "e" variants (`jbe`, `jae`, ...)

(the above/below couple differs from the greater/less couple in that `a`/`b` are for comparison between unsigned values, `g`/`l` for signed values; also, there are [a lot of synonyms](http://www.sandpile.org/x86/cc.htm), in particular `je` is a synonymous for `jz` AKA "jump if zero", and `jne` for `jnz` AKA "jump if not zero"; disassemblers may produce `jz` or `je`, it's the same)

Now, coming to your case:

- `test reg,reg` is perfectly equivalent to `cmp reg,0` ([apart from the status of AF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147173/testl-eax-against-eax/38032818#38032818), which is irrelevant); this is easily understood:

  - `test` performs an `and` between the operands and sets the flags according to the result; so, `test reg,reg` just sets the flags according to `reg` (`and`ing a number with itself is a nop);
  - `cmp b,a` calculates `b-a` and sets the flags according to the result; given that `b-0 == b`, `cmp b,0` just sets the flags according to `b`, exactly as `test b,b`.
- the `cmovg` is an instance of the `cmovCC` instruction, with condition code `g`, i.e. "move if **g**reater".

So, your

```
test rdx,rdx
cmovg rax,rcx
```

is equivalent to

```
cmp rdx,0
cmovg rax,rcx
```

which plainly reads as "compare rdx with zero, if it's greater move rcx in rax".