# Use of "or" mnemonic in assembly if-statement from compiled C code

Tags: c, assembly, x86

In [*Shellcoder's Handbook: Discovering and Exploiting Security Holes*](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/The+Shellcoder%27s+Handbook%3A+Discovering+and+Exploiting+Security+Holes%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780470080238), I found a comparison between this `C` code example:

```
    int number;
if (number<0)
{
...more code...
}
```

and its compiled `assembly` code (IA 32 architecture):

```
number dw 0
mov eax,number
or eax,eax
jge label
<no>
label :<yes>
```

what is the purpose of the `or eax,eax` command? Shouldn't it be `comp eax,0` ?

Comment: I'm guessing that it's just an alternative way of setting the status flags for a comparaison of the contents of the register to 0 (zero_flag will be set to true if `eax` contains 0, otherwise false). I don't have the tables, but it may also be cheaper in CPU cycles versus the `comp` instruction. Like, doing `xor eax, eax` to set a register to 0.

Comment: `or eax, eax` will OR `eax` with itself and then set the arithmetic status flags  of the  CPU accordingly. Read the documentation for `OR` and see what it does. Then check the documentation for what `jge` actually does. Specifically, if `eax` is zero, the zero flag will be set. The  combination of `or eax, eax` with `jge label` will check if `eax` is greater than or equal to zero and jump if it is. Doing `or eax, eax` followed by an instruction that acts on the  flags is a very common pattern.

Comment: so, i checked better `jge`, it jumps if SF=OF. Being that OF is cleared in an OR operation, this should jump only if `number` is positive (SF = 0), thus avoiding the portion of the code inside the `if` statement. would this be correct?

Comment: @AntonH Probably not cheaper in cycles, but shorter in bytes, since it doesn't have to encode an immediate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38032818/4271923 (`or` is less performant option than `test` in this case)

Comment: @AntonH `or` **may** be slower than `cmp` because of creating false dependency on the result of `or`. While both `cmp` and `test` are known to CPU to discard the result of operation (except flags), so they don't create dependency on the result of operation itself.

Comment: The only reason to use `or eax,eax` would be if you need to avoid bytes with the high bit set so your shellcode can be plain ASCII text.  [`or r/m32, r32` has opcode `0x0B`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/OR), but [`test r/m32, r32` has opcode `0x85`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/TEST).  Using `OR` instead of `TEST` seems to be some kind of legacy habit among some programmers.  And BTW, `cmp eax, 0` won't work in shellcode for most buffer overflows, because it contains a zero byte.  (end of implicit-length string)

Comment: Also, that's some bogus code.  `dw 0` is only a 16 bit `word`, so a `dword` load into `eax` will load 2 bytes beyond the end of `number`.  It's also weird to put `number` right next to the instructions.

Comment: I think the or eax,eax falls into the category of xor eax,eax.  (much) smaller encoding than a cmp or mov, saves on program space, a habit going way back to when it mattered a lot more.  I would have to check the docs you could probably do an and eax,eax as well...at least on some instruction sets (rather than a compare with zero).

Answer (score 1):

That kind of self-comparison is used to set flag values. The x86 instruction set often has equivalent ways of performing the same operation.