# Count of negative numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, carryflag

```
dosseg
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    array db -1, -2, -3, -4, 1,2, 3, -5
.code
main PROC 
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    xor ax, ax
    xor dx, dx ; reset dx 
    lea si, array
    mov cx, 8
    back: 
      mov bl, [si]
      cmp al, bl
      jc continue ; carry will be generated if number in bl is positive
      inc dx
      continue: 
        inc si
        clc
    loop back
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
main ENDP 
end main
```

I wrote the above program to find the number of negative integers in an array.
Debugging showed that when SI is pointing at -1, the carry flag becomes 1 but it should not as the value at that instant in BL is FFh (negative) and in AL is 00h, so subtracting negative number from 0 should not generate a carry. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I replaced the erroneous part with :

```
 test bl, bl 
 jns continue
```

and now it works as expected but I still don't know why the `cmp` method did not work.

Comment: `cmp` method didn't work becase you've chosen incorrect predicate which followed the compare instruction (`jc`  instead of `jle`).

Comment: @vitsoft jc = jump if carry, so the subtraction should generate a carry if bl has a positive value; shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does set CF, if by *positive value* you mean values between 0x01 and 0xFF.   Values between 0x80 and 0xFF are treated as **unsigned positive** when the compare is followed by `jc`, `ja`, `jb` . When you want to interpret them as **signed**, use `js`, `jg`, `jl`.

Comment: The fun way since you have exactly 8 bytes: `movq xmm0, qword ptr [array]` (load 8 bytes) / `pmovmskb eax, xmm0` (pack the sign bit of each byte into an integer register) / `popcnt eax,eax` (count set bits).  Would also work easily for 4 or 16 byte arrays, or for other compile-time-constant sizes do 2 loads and shift out overlapping bytes.  With more you'd want to start accumulating counts in vector regs, like `pcmpgtb` to compare for `0 > x` / `psubb xmm1, xmm0` to do `total -= (0 or -1)`, up to 255 iterations of 16 bytes.  Then accumulate with `psadbw` against zero.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare `al=0` with `bl`, carry flag (alias Below flag) will be set for **any** value in `bl` except for `bl=0`, because 0 is below any unsigned number in the range 0x01..0xFF.
Your array contains 8bit **signed** integer numbers. When we compare signed numbers, instead of adverbs **below|above** we use **lower|greater** which take into account Signum flag and Overflow flag.

Instead of `jc continue ; carry will be generated if number in bl is positive` use
`jle continue ; Jump if al=bl or if SF<>OF`.

Better readable solution is to replace `cmp al,bl` with
`test bl,bl`
`jns continue  ; Skip incrementing dx when signum of bl is not set.`

See also [Jcc](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc). You might output the result from DX using the returned errorlevel, just `mov al,dl` before `int 21h`.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you just want to branch, use signed or signed-compare conditions

`test reg,reg` / `jns non_negative` (not sign-bit-set) or `jnl non_negative` (not less-than) are equivalent after a compare with zero.

That uses the FLAGS and conditions for their normal semantic meaning, i.e. doing a normal signed compare.
(`test same,same` is equivalent to `cmp` against zero, always clearing OF and CF, and is [a well-known optimization for `cmp reg, 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147173/testl-eax-against-eax/38032818#38032818))

What you're doing doesn't set CF in a way that reflects the sign-bit, so a `jc` (jump if CF set) isn't useful.  You're counting non-zero numbers, ones where `0U < (unsigned)x` is true.

---

### Getting the carry flag set according to the MSB

**It's only interesting to get your condition into CF if you're going to take advantage of that**
by using `adc dx, 0` or `sbb dx, -1` to conditionally increment DX (when CF is 1 or 0, respectively.)

The `sbb` version is like `dx -= -1 + CF` so CF either cancels out the -1, or you subtract -1, i.e. add 1.

One way to get CF set according to the sign bit of a byte is simply to shift it out, e.g. `shl bl, 1`, if you don't mind destroying the value in BL.  Equivalently, `add bl,bl` is also a 2-byte instruction but can run on more execution units on modern CPUs.  (They both set FLAGS the same way, including CF).

It's not possible with a compare against zero.  `0 - x` always has a borrow (CF=1) for any non-zero `x`, and `x - 0` never has carry-out.

Without modifying the register value, it *is* possible with `cmp`, though: `0x7f - x` has unsigned wrapping (i.e. borrow output that sets CF) for x>=0x80 unsigned.  i.e. for values with their MSB set.

```
   xor dx, dx              ; count = 0
   mov si, OFFSET array    ; LEA takes more bytes than mov-immediate.  Never use LEA without a register, except for x86-64 RIP-relative

;;;  The interesting part
   mov  al, 0x7f           ; outside the loop
back:                      ; do {
   cmp  al, [si]             ; CF = 0x7F <(unsigned)[SI].  i.e. MSB set in [si]
   adc  dx, 0                ; count negative values
;;;  then the rest of the loop

   inc  si
   cmp  si, OFFSET array+8   ; the LOOP instruction isn't fast on most modern CPUs, and we're hard-coding the array length anyway.  Or just put a label at the end of it and use that.
   jne  back                ; }while(p != endp)
```

You don't need `clc` in this or your version.  CF isn't "sticky"; anything that updates its value sets it to 0 or 1 regardless of the old value.  And it's not an input for `cmp`.

We can't set CF=1 for `bl < 0` (aka `bl >= 0x80U`) with `cmp bl, constant`, unfortunately.  It *only* works the way you're doing it, setting another register to compare against.  (`cmp reg, 123` exists, `cmp 123,reg` doesn't; most 2-operand instructions modify their destination and wouldn't make sense with an immediate destination, so it would be a special case to have yet another opcode for `cmp` in the other direction.)

**But you can do `cmp bl, 0x80` to *clear* CF when `bl < 0x80`, i.e. when its sign bit isn't set.**

```
   cmp  byte ptr [si], 0x80        ; CF = [si] < (unsigned)0x80, i.e. non-negative
   sbb  dx, -1                     ; count when CF=0, negative values
```

---

Loading the value into a register with `mov bl, [si]` can be helpful for debugging, making it show up in your debugger's window of registers instead of having to examine memory.  But that's not necessary; `cmp` works with reg or memory operands (or an immediate), saving an instruction.

---

As a further optimization for code-size inside the loop, [`scasb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/scas:scasb:scasw:scasd) is equivalent to `cmp al, es:[di]` / `inc di` (but the `inc` part doesn't set FLAGS.)  And it's actually `dec di` if DF is set, so you'd want `cld` somewhere in your program before a loop using "string" instructions to make sure they go in the forward direction.

Using `scasb` means you *need* to use AL for that.  Without `scasb`, you could count into AL inside the loop, where it could be the exit status for your DOS call.  (Perhaps that's why you were trying to use AL=0, if you wanted to exit(0) instead of returning a value.)

`scasb` isn't particularly fast on modern CPUs, but it is on real 8086; so is the `loop` instruction, because they're both compact code-size.  `loop` is a special-case optimization for `dec cx`/`jnz` (but also without affecting FLAGS).

---

**Or with 386 instructions,** `bt word ptr [si], 7` to [Bit Test](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bt) that bit, putting the result in CF where you can `add dx, 0`.  `bt` is slow on modern CPUs with `bt mem, reg` (like 10 uops) because it can index outside the word indexed by the addressing mode. So it would be less efficient put `bt word ptr [array], cx` in a loop with `cx` initially = `7` and incrementing with `add cx, 8` inside the loop.  But that would work.

`bt` is not too bad with `bt mem, imm`, only 2 uops on most modern Intel and 1 on some AMD (https://uops.info/).  It's only a single uop for `bt reg, imm` or `bt reg,reg`, like `cmp`, if you want to load first.  (It can't macro-fuse with branches into a single uops, so if branching instead of adc, a `cmp`/`jle` would be more efficient as well as more readable.)  On AMD, `bts`/`btr`/`btc` to also modify the bit are slower than `bt` even for `reg,reg`, decoding to extra uops.

---

### SSE2 + popcnt to check 4, 8, or 16 bytes at once

The extra fun way, since you have exactly 8 bytes, uses SSE2 and `popcnt`.  (Yes this can work in 16-bit real mode, unlike AVX.  In a bootloader and maybe DOS you'd have to manually enable the control-register bits that make SSE instructions not fault.  Of course it only works on CPUs with `popcnt`, like Nehalem and later from 2008 or so, otherwise use `pcmpgtb` / `psadbw` / `movq` for just SSE2, or SSE1 using MMX registers.)

```
  movq      xmm0, qword ptr [array]  ; load 8 bytes (zero-extending to a 16-byte XMM reg)
  pmovmskb  ax, xmm0                 ; pack the sign bit of each byte into an integer reg
  popcnt    ax, ax                   ; count set bits = sign bits of the bytes
```

Would also work easily for 4 or 16 byte arrays, or for other compile-time-constant sizes, do 2 loads and shift out overlapping bytes.

For other element sizes, there's `movmskps` (dword) and `movmskpd` (qword)

With a larger array, you'd want to start accumulating counts in vector regs, like `pcmpgtb` to compare for `0 > x` / `psubb xmm1, xmm0` to do `total -= (0 or -1)`, up to 255 iterations of 16 bytes.  Then accumulate with `psadbw` against zero.  Same problem as [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541129/how-to-count-character-occurrences-using-simd) but replacing `pcmpeqb` with `pcmpgtb`.